# Drawing string at the middle of line

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to draw some text (a number) in the middle of a line drawn with `Graphics.DrawLine` like this:
[image]

1 and 2 are buttons. I achieved this by using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964109/draw-string-in-the-middle-of-line-drawn-by-graphics-drawline).
The problem with this solution is that it doesn't take into account the fact that the line start can be vertically lower than the end point (in which case the text overlaps with the line and at a certain point disappears as here:
[image].

I know how to solve the main issue here about the start point being vertically lower but how can I make it so that it doesn't overlap with the line as in the following image?
[image]

Comment: You need to show us the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: Create a function that returns the __center point between 2 points__. Then __measure the text bounds rectangle__ and  draw  at the mid pint offset by the bounds size!

Comment: If you use RotateTransform + TranslateTransform to draw that line then you'll also have a *much* easier time drawing that string in the right place.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, I'll try this approach. How do I rotate the text after I've used RotateTransform + TranslateTransform for the line?

Comment: The point is that you don't have to, the rotate transform is still in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Based on comments.

I believe you're looking for something like below (please note I used test data, a little work will be required.  This takes your 2 points, creates a median, measures your string, offsets the median, and draws the string.

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     var pt1 = new Point(25, 25);
    var pt2 = new Point(100, 10);
    var ptMed = new Point((pt1.X + pt2.X) / 2, (pt1.Y + pt2.Y) / 2);
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var lbl = "1";
    var offset = g.MeasureString(lbl, this.Font);
    ptMed.Y -= (int)offset.Height;
    ptMed.X -= (int)offset.Width;
    var p = new Pen(Brushes.White);
    g.DrawLine(p, pt1, pt2);
    g.DrawString(lbl, this.Font, Brushes.White, ptMed);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: The most important work that will be required is inserting `using` blocks to prevent all those resources from being leaked! Also, **never use `CreateGraphics`**. Do all drawing in the `Paint` event handler.

Comment: your offset applied only to Y, so with the different slope label will be overlaped

Comment: MeasureString returns a Size, so you need to call it only once. And if your are using Brushes.White you may as well use Pens.White..

Comment: How would I go about rotating the text as well to match the angle of the line?

Comment: With more extreme angles the text location is in a bad spot